# Deletes in a stored procedure fail silently when called from VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I am trying to delete certain rows out of my database by a `Artikelnr` (`articleNr` in Dutch).

When I try to execute my code from access it doesn't throw an error, but it just doesn't delete anything either.

Am I missing something here?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name =      'spVerwijderArtikel') 
    DROP PROCEDURE spVerwijderArtikel
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE spVerwijderArtikel
    (@ArtikelNr integer)
AS 
BEGIN Transaction
    DELETE FROM artikelprijs
    WHERE ArtikelNr = @ArtikelNr

    DELETE FROM Artikel 
    WHERE ArtikelNr = @ArtikelNr

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK
        RAISERROR ('Error tijdens het uitvoeren', 16 , 1)
        RETURN
    END 

    COMMIT
GO
```

And my code from access trying to execute the stored procedure:

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
  "Initial Catalog=KlantArtikelOpdracht;" & _
  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute("EXEC spVerwijderArtikel'" & TxTArtikelNr & "'")

End Sub
```

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: With an integer, I'd say you need `Execute("EXEC spVerwijderArtikel " & TxTArtikelNr)`

Comment: @Andre That won't matter. SQL will implicitly cast it. 

However, is the OP sure that TxTArtikelNr when concatenated with the command is actually an int? Also, you should look at using SQL Query Parameterisation to avoid SQL Injection attacks (also it's a good habit)

Comment: You should look into using try/catch in your sql. It isn't going to fix this problem but your code will be a lot cleaner. And parameterize your queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Are you setting a value for TxTArtikelNr  anywhere? If not its running the stored procedure with TxTArtikelNr  = ''.

Comment: TxTArtikelNr is just a plain textbox, when I go into debugging I see that the textbox input is in the statement so the textbox input works.

Answer (score 0):

Add the statement

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

as the very first statement of your stored procedure (before `BEGIN Transaction`). That will allow the `RAISERROR` to be passed back to the VBA code if an error occurs when you execute the stored procedure.

Other suggestions:

Don't use a `Recordset` since the stored procedure does not return rows.

Consider using an `ADODB.Command` object with `.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc` and a proper `ADODB.Parameter` to specify the `@ArtikelNr` value.